# Getting an image on screen with SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've been trying to have a bitmap image displayed on screen but I can't figure out why it's not displaying it for the life of me. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

bool init(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *surface) {
    bool success {true};

    if (SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Could not initialize video: " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
        success = false;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);

    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Could not create window: " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
        success = false;
    }

    surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    return success;
}

bool loadMedia(SDL_Surface *image) {
    bool success {true};

    image = SDL_LoadBMP("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Files\\Programming\\C++\\game\\Untitled.bmp");

    if (image == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Could not load image: " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

void close(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *surface, SDL_Surface *image) {
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    surface = nullptr;
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    image = nullptr;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = nullptr;

    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool quit {false};
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Window *window {nullptr};
    SDL_Surface *surface {nullptr};
    SDL_Surface *image {nullptr};

    if (!init(window, surface)) {
        std::cout << "Initialization failed\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!loadMedia(image)) {
        std::cout << "Loading media failed\n";
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, surface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    while (!quit) {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = true;
            break;
        default: break;
        }
    }

    close(window, surface, image);

    return 0;
}
```

The file structure is like so:

```
-game/
  -image.bmp
  -main.cpp
  -main.exe
  -Makefile
```

Makefile is like so:

```
all : main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -IC:\SDL2\include\SDL2 -LC:\SDL2\lib -w -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o main
```

SDL version 2.0.14 64-bit

mingw 64-bit

Windows 10 64-bit

I don't even know how much more information is necessary.

I have tried using events, not using events, using an absolute path, making the variables global, different file formats, trying to display it using a renderer and a texture, putting everything in main, making the image the same size as the screen, using ImageMagick `convert` as per the suggestion of an answer on some other thread on here, disabling the console window with the `-Wl,-subsystem,windows` compiler flag, but nothing I did has worked. Any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing parameters to `init()` - but the function receives a *copy* of those things.  Then you change the copies passed into the function so they point somewhere else - but that doesn't change where the original pointers point.  Then when you return to `main()` you use the original pointers which are still pointing to null.

It's the same as writing this:

```
void f(int x) {
    x=2; // change the copy of x passed to this function
}

int main() {
    int x=1;
    f(x);
    printf("%d\n",x); // prints the original value: 1
}
```

When what you should do is pass pointers to the things you want to change and then inside the function change the contents of the parameters:

```
void f(int *x) {
    *x=2; // change the contents of the pointer: the original x
}

int main() {
    int x=1;
    f(&x); // pass a pointer to x
    printf("%d\n",x); // prints the changed value: 2
}
```

So, in your case, what you need to do is pass pointers to the things you want to change (a pointer to window and a pointer to surface) and then inside `init()` change the contents of the parameters:

```
bool init(SDL_Window **window, SDL_Surface **surface) {
    // ...
    *window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
    // ...
    *surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ...
    SDL_Window *window {nullptr};
    SDL_Surface *surface {nullptr};
    // ...
    if (!init(&window, &surface)) {
        std::cout << "Initialization failed\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see! I remember specifically checking if pointers are passed by value by default, but I guess that I misunderstood. So to pass pointers by value I have to specify the parameters to be pointers of pointers, and then pass in the addresses of said pointers. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Sencres Everything is passed by value in C.  So you always have to pass a pointer to the thing you want to change.  C++ has references.  If you want to see how I can edit my answer to add that.